# Laravel Querying from array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

My users are able to tag other users in a comment, this returns the Username and the following markup:

```
<span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at-query="@josh"><a href="/profile/joshuaTest" data-type="mentionable" data-id="undefined" data-name="joshuaTest">joshuaTest</a></span>
<span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at-query="@jish"><a href="/profile/jishy" data-type="mentionable" data-id="undefined" data-name="jishy">jishy</a></span>
```

I'm doing a preg_match on some regex to retreive some data, I would then like to query based on these bits of data. Example:

```
$matches = array();
$t = preg_match_all('/data-name="(.*?)\"/', $str, $matches);
//I am aware that $t will provide an int of how many matches exist
```

$matches will give me exact usernames, with these I can query the database.

I would then like to do something like the following in side of a foreach, I am wondering if it's possible to loop this query with the results of the matched usernames

```
foreach($matches as $match)
    {
        $j = User::whereUsername($match[0,1,2,3 or whatever here (Until it equals $t)])->first();
    }
```

and then notify the users found by their username via the Notifynder package:

```
Notifynder::category('userpropped')
    ->from(1)
    ->to(//UserID from above)
    ->url('/notifications')
    ->send();
```

Essentially, I would like to grab the users from their usernames, take their IDS and loop through them while passing them to the notifynder function

Is this something that I can achieve or have I gone about things in an incorrect fashion?

Thanks!

Comment: Need context.  What is `$matches`?  Is it a series of html elements?  What's with the `data-name` attribute in your regular expression?

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the problem that you are having? You should try to provide some example input, your expected output, and where things are not working.

Comment: Will update my question, sorry all!

Comment: You need something like User::where('name', '=', 'joshuaTest'); The where clause will loop through all records for you.